# Oracle 11g: Extracting and Counting XML elements

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery

I have XML type data stored in an Oracle 11g database. A sketchy version of my data would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
<record_number>12345</record_number>
<record_type> book </record_type>
</record>
```

Data manipulation functions such as:

```
SELECT XML_Type FROM Metadata
```

specify the column where each row contains a well-formatted XML file (with many tags and elements). I am struggling to extract and count the number of occurrences for each `<record_type>` element. For instance, I would like to know how many times the XML tag `<record_type>` has the element 'book', 'article', etc. I do not know the entire list of elements associated to the tag , though.

Thanks,

I.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on exactly how your data is stored (i.e. do you have 1 row in the table is 1 XML document that looks like the sample you posted or do you have 1 row in the table that is 1 XML document that has many different record tags in it) the simplest possible approach is something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  2                     <record>
  3                       <record_number>12345</record_number>
  4                       <record_type> book </record_type>
  5                     </record>' xml
  6                from dual
  7              union all
  8              select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  9                        <record>
 10                           <record_number>6789</record_number>
 11                           <record_type> magazine </record_type>
 12                        </record>' xml
 13                 from dual)
 14  select xmltype(t.xml).extract( '//record_number/text()' ) record_number,
 15         xmltype(t.xml).extract( '//record_type/text()' ) record_type
 16*   from t
SQL> /

RECORD_NUMBER        RECORD_TYPE
-------------------- ------------------------------
12345                 book
6789                  magazine
```

Once you've extracted the data, it should be easy enough to count or otherwise aggregate the data.

Comment: Justin, thanks for your reply, unfortunately I do not seem to get my head around it. The data is stored under a column called 'XML Type' (from the table 'Metadata) and each row is a rather elaborated XML metadata file (yes, several record tags). Can you please add some more details on what your code actually does? Thank indeed, apologies for my non-existent knowledge of XQuery...